# Changing DNS server password on windows 2008

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm having a problem with changing DNS passwords in windows 2008 R2.

In order there are 2 DNS servers: ns1 and ns2 with full redundancy and 2 machines.
When I change one of the machine's administrator password, redundancy failes and DNS manager says `access denied`.

How can I change the password? 
The servers were configured by another person and now I'am in charge.
Thanks.
[this picture discribed problem when i changed the administrator account of ns2 password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPGB8.png)

Comment: `In order there are 2 DNS servers: ns1 and ns2 with full redundancy and 2 machines. When I change one of the machine's administrator password, redundancy failes` - I don't understand what any of that means. Please add more detail about the problem to your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks anyone who answer this topic.
I Found the answer
if you have 2 DNS server like this and not have active directory
**after change password you should restart machines or use the powershell** commands for change it. 
tahanks.

Answer (score 2):

This has no relevance whatsoever to the DNS service or "redundancy", it's simply the DNS *management console* telling you it can't remotely connect to the other server; which is to be expected, if (as I'm guessing) you are using local accounts on those machines.

Either you should use the same username and password on both servers, or (much better) you should join them to an Active Directory domain and use a domain account to administer them.